# Error in running bookdown package

Tags: r, bookdown

I have multiple Red files that I am joining with `bookdown`. This has gone OK until I got the following error message
label: error_chunk

> Quitting from lines 2941-2947 (bookdown-demo.Rmd) 
>   Error in model.frame.default(formula = glu ~ age, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
>     variable lengths differ (found for 'age')
>   Calls:  ... lm -> eval -> eval ->  -> model.frame.default
>   Execution halted
>
> Exited with status 1.

error_chunk is the following code:-

````
```{r error_chunk}
sample1 <- data.frame(glu=c(120,130,140,150), age=c(55,60,65,70))
attach(sample1)
#For linear regression analysis, the function lm (linear model) is used
fit<-lm (glu~age)
print(fit)
```
````

This is straightforward and obviously runs on its own and produces its own Rmd document.

What is occurring in the `bookdown` environment?

Answer (score 0):

The code works in bookdown if I use the variable names sample1$glu & sample1$age.
Don't understand why attach() doesn't seem to work.

Comment: a better approach would be to use the `data` argument of `lm` . So `lm (glu ~ age, data=sample1)` . (ps dont use `attach` - it will lead to problems)